# AudioKit v5 - What is the best way to program polyphony?

Tags: swift, audiokit, synth

I am trying to use AudioKit v5 to build a simple synthesizer app that plays a certain frequency whenever a button is pressed.

I would like there to be 28 buttons. However, I do not know if I should use the DunneAudioKit `Synth` class or create a dictionary of 28 AudioKit `DynamicOscillators`.

If I use the `Synth` class, I currently have no way of changing the waveform of the synth. If I use the dictionary of `DynamicOscillators`, I will have to start 28 oscillators and keep them running throughout the lifetime of the app. Neither scenario seems that great. One option only allows for a certain sound while the other one is energy inefficient.

Is there a better way to allow for polyphony using AudioKit? A way that is efficient and also able to produce many different kinds of sound? AudioKit SynthOne is a great example of what I am trying to achieve.

I downloaded "AudioKit Synth One - The Ultimate Guide" by Francis Preve and from that I learned that SynthOne uses 2 Oscillators, a Sub-Oscillator, an FM Pair, and a Noise Generator to produce its sounds. However, the eBook does not explain how to actually code a polyphonic synthesizer using these 5 generators. I know that SynthOne's source code is online. I have downloaded it, but it is a little too advanced for me to understand. However, if someone can help explain how to use just those 5 objects to create a polyphonic synthesizer, that would be incredible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how they did things in AudioKit 4 which Synth One uses. I would speculate that it has an internal oscillator array bank when polyphonic mode is enabled. So essentially one instance of an oscillator per voice.

In the AudioKit 5 documentation it says Dunne Synth is the only polyphonic oscillator at this time, but I did added a WIP polyphonic oscillator example in the AudioKit Cookbook. I'm not sure how much of a resource hog it is. 28 instances seems excessive so you might be able to get by with around 10 and change the frequencies for each voice with button presses.

The third option would be to use something like AppleSampler or DunneSampler and make instruments based on single cycle wavetable audio files. This is more of a workaround and wouldn't give as much control over certain parameters, but it would be lighter on the resources.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar question and tried several ways of making a versatile polyphonic sampler.

It's true that the `AppleSampler` and the `DunneSampler` support polyphone; however, I needed a sampler that I could control with more precision on a note-by-note bases; i.e. playing each "voice" with unique playback parameters like playspeed, etc.

I found that building a sampler based on the `AudioPlayer` was the right path for me; and there, I created a member variable inside my sampler "voice" that kept track of when that voice was "busy"; when a "voice" is assigned a note to play, it marks itself as "busy", and when it's done, the callback from the `AudioPlayer` executes a function that sets the voice's "busy" variable to "false".

I then use a "conductor" to find the first available voice that is not "busy" to play a sound.

Here is a snippet:

```
import AudioKit
import AudioKitUI
import AVFoundation
import Keyboard
import Combine
import SwiftUI
import DunneAudioKit



class AudioPlayerVoice: ObservableObject, HasAudioEngine {
    // For audio playback
    let engine = AudioEngine()
    let player = AudioPlayer()
    let variSpeed: VariSpeed

    
    var voiceNumber = 0
    var busy : Bool
    
    
    init() {
        variSpeed = VariSpeed(player)
        engine.output = variSpeed
        
        do {
            try engine.start()
        } catch {
            Log("AudioKit did not start!")
        }
        
        busy = false
        variSpeed.rate = 1.0
        player.isBuffered = true
        player.completionHandler = donePlaying
    }
    
    func play(buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer) {
        // Set this voice to busy so that new incoming notes are not palyed here
        busy = true
        
        // Load buffer into player
        player.load(buffer: buffer)
        
        // Compare buffer and audioplayer formats
        // print("Player format 1: ")
        // print(player.outputFormat)
        // print("Buffer format: ")
        // print(buffer.format)
        
        // Set AudioPlayer format to be the same as buffer format
        player.playerNode.engine?.connect( player.playerNode, to: player.mixerNode, format: buffer.format)
        
        // Compare buffer and audioplayer formats again to see if the above line changed anything
//        print("Player format 2: ")
//        print(player.outputFormat)

        //  Play sound with a completion callback
        player.play(completionCallbackType: .dataPlayedBack)
    }
    
    func donePlaying() {
        print("done!")
        busy = false
    }
    
}

class AudioPlayerConductor: ObservableObject {
    // Mark Published so View updates label on changes
    @Published private(set) var lastPlayed: String = "None"
    
    let voiceCount = 16
    
    var soundFileList: [String] = []
    var buffers : [AVAudioPCMBuffer] = []
    var players: [AudioPlayerVoice] = []
    var sampleDict: [String: AVAudioPCMBuffer] = [:]
  

    func loadAudioFiles() {
        // Build audio file name list
        let fileNameExtension = ".wav"
        if let files = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath + "/Samples" ){
//            var counter = 0
            ///print("Files... " + files)
            for file in files {
                if file.hasSuffix(fileNameExtension) {
                    let name = file.prefix(file.count - fileNameExtension.count)
                    
                    // add sound file name without extension to our soundFileist
                    soundFileList.append(String(name))
                    
                    // get url for current sound
                    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: String(name),  withExtension: "wav", subdirectory: "Samples")
                    
                    // read audiofile into an AVAudioFile
                    let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: url!)
                    
                    // find the audio format and frame count
                    let audioFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
                    let audioFrameCount = UInt32(audioFile.length)
                    
                    // create a new AVAudioPCMBuffer and read from the AVAudioFile into the AVAudioPCMBuffer
                    let audioFileBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: audioFormat, frameCapacity: audioFrameCount)
                    try! audioFile.read(into: audioFileBuffer!)
                    
                    // updated the sampleDict dictionary with "name" / "buffer" key / value
                    sampleDict[String(name)] = audioFileBuffer
                    //print("loading... " + name)
                    //print(".......... " + url!.absoluteString)
                }
            }
        }
        
        print("Loaded Samples:")
        print(soundFileList)

    }
    
    
    func initializeSamplerVoices() {
        for i in 1...voiceCount {
            let newAudioPlayerVoice = AudioPlayerVoice()
            newAudioPlayerVoice.voiceNumber = i
            players.append(newAudioPlayerVoice)
        }
    }
    
    func playWithAvailableVoice (bufferToPlay: AVAudioPCMBuffer, playspeed: Float) {
        for i in 0...(voiceCount-1) {
            if (!players[i].busy) {
                players[i].variSpeed.rate = playspeed
                players[i].play(buffer: bufferToPlay)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    
    func playXY(x: Double, y: Double) {
        let playspeed = Float(AliSwift.scale(x, 0.0, UIScreen.screenWidth, 0.1, 3.0))
        let soundNumber = Int(AliSwift.scale(y, 0.0, UIScreen.screenHeight, 0 , Double(soundFileList.count - 1)))

        let soundBuffer = sampleDict[soundFileList[soundNumber]]

        
        playWithAvailableVoice(bufferToPlay: soundBuffer!, playspeed: playspeed)
    }

    init() {
        loadAudioFiles()
        initializeSamplerVoices()
    }
}


struct ContentViewAudioPlayer: View {
    @StateObject var conductor = AudioPlayerConductor()
    // @StateObject var samplerVoice = AudioPlayerVoice()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .onTapGesture { location in
                        print("Tapped at \(location)")
                        let someSound = conductor.sampleDict.randomElement()!
                        let someSoundName = someSound.key
                        let someSoundBuffer = someSound.value
                        print("Playing: " + someSoundName)
                        conductor.playXY(x: location.x, y: location.y)
                    }
        }
        .onAppear {
            // conductor.start()
        }
        .onDisappear {
            // conductor.stop()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentViewAudioPlayer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()

    }
}
```